# Multiple chained knex joins changing output format

Tags: javascript, json, join, knex.js

I am converting the following query to knex.

```
select e.email, p.id, a.started
from person p join gift g on p.id = g.user
    join ants a on g.latest = a.id
    join emailant e on p.id = e.user
group by p.id
having MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, a.created, now(6))) > 0;
```

knex version:

```
let sql: QueryBuilder = knex 
        .select('e.email as Email', 'p.id', 'a.started')
        .from ('person as p') 
        .join('gift as g', 'p.id', '=', 'g.person') . // Works to this point
        .join('emailants as e','p.id', '=', 'e.person') // Output changes here
        .join('ants as a', 'g.latest', '=', 'a.id')
        .groupBy('p.id')
        .havingRaw('MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, a.started, now(6))) > ?', [0]);  
return sql.map((row: any) => { 
  const elementObj = {"elements": row};
    return JSON.stringify(elementObj);
});
```

However, after the second join, the output does not look like JSON but rather an array of characters.

```
{
  "0": "{",
  "1": "\"",
  "2": "e",
  "3": "l",
  "4": "e",
  "5": "m",
  "6": "e",
  "7": "n",
  "8": "t",
  "9": "s",
  "10": "\"",
  "11": ":",
  "12": "{",
  "13": "\"",
  "14": "E",
  "15": "m",
  "16": "a",
  "17": "i",
  "18": "l",
  "19": "\"",
  "20": ":",
.
.
.
```

1. Am I using chained joins correctly?
2. Is there another knex method that needs to be included in the chain to remedy this?
3. Should I have used knex.raw methods instead?

Thank you in advance for any enlightenment you can give.
Pete

Answer (score 0):

There is no `map` any more as part of knex API, therefore, you need to `await` the result, and only then map over it.

```js
let sql = knex
  .select('e.email as Email', 'p.id', 'a.started')
  .from('person as p')
  .join('gift as g', 'p.id', '=', 'g.person') // Works to this point
  .join('emailants as e', 'p.id', '=', 'e.person') // Output changes here
  .join('ants as a', 'g.latest', '=', 'a.id')
  .groupBy('p.id')
  .havingRaw('MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, a.started, now(6))) > ?', [0]);

return sql.then((rows) => {
  // -------^
  return rows.map((row) => { 
    const elementObj = {"elements": row};
    return JSON.stringify(elementObj);
  });
});
```

Comment: It turns out that the map function used by the rows array doesn't like when there is only one record.  When there are two or more JSON objects in rows, they print correctly.  Not sure if this is a bug or not.  Thank you @felixmosh for the input.  I have updated my code accordingly and will need to find a workaround for this behavior.

Comment: It’s not true, I get an array of one object where there is one result